# Regex to match after double backslash slash until .com

Tags: regex

I've been trying to regex the following message:

> Netlogon has failed an additional 130 authentication requests in the
> last 30 minutes. The requests timed out before they could be sent to
> domain controller \\AA-SRV85.xx.acme.com in domain XX. Please see
> http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2654097 for more information.

So far, I've managed to understand that if use the following, I will find a match for \\AA-SVR85.xx.acme.com

```
\\\\AA\-SRV85\.xx\.acme\.com
```

But the thing is, I have multiple servers in my environment and the server name will certainly vary.

Can someone please explain how this should be done?

My goal is to match everything after the double backslash until the end of the domain (.com).

Comment: please let us know two or more possible server names so we infer the pattern out of it.

Comment: They pretty much follow this naming convention with minor variation such AAASRV999.xx.acme.com, AAASRV99.xx.acme.com. All the answers provided so far were tested in regex101 website and none of them work. I also tried in my Splunk SPL language and no luck either

Comment: please check out my updated answer and knowledge!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will match "everything after the double backslash until the end of the domain (.com)." As requested in your question.

```
\\\\.*?\.com
```

You may want to modify it a bit to match upper or lower case `COM`:

```
\\\\.*?\.[Cc][Oo][Mm]
```

Here is how it works:

`\\` matches `\`

`.` matches any character (except for line terminators)

`*?` matches the previous token between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy)

`\.` matches a period

`[Cc]` matches `C` or `c`

`[Oo]` matches `O` or `o`

`[Mm]` matches `M` or `m`

> Replacing the `.` with `[^ ]` so that it won't match spaces between
> the `\\` and the `.com` is probably an improvement also...

Answer (score 0):

`^\\\\[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+.com$`

As per your question, a

- ^ means regex match starts here,
- \\ - matches a \, so two pairs of \\ matches the two \\ in your URL.
- [a-zA-Z0-9-.] matches the characters from a-z, A-Z, 0-9, dash, and a period.
- + means match the above condition infinite times.
- a .com matches literal .com
- $ signifies regex ends here.

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate your contribution!

Answer (score 0):

```
/\\\\\w+-\w+\.xx\.\w+.com/ig
```

here we have

- `\\` for matching `\`
- `\w+` for matching one or more character
- `-` for matching `-`
- `\.` for matching `.`
- `com` for exact string match
- `g` for globally search in string.
- `i` for case in-sensitive.

Comment: I tried on regex101 website with all different flavours and none of them work. Do you have any idea why that happen?

Comment: @dgoamaral now I updated the regex please check again let me know!

Comment: Thank you Taimoor! I really appreciate your support! :)